# Having a little bug with my first Arduino/Python project [Reaction.py], time.sleep seems to be causing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to complete my first projects, nothing special but having few problems.

**1.** When I run the code, the diode is constantly on, but it should go off. When I close the program I get error for this line

**time.sleep(random.uniform(2,5))**

Seems like it doesn't like being in the while loop.

**2.** While the diode is still on, if either of the players presses its button, it should get -2 points in penalty. But since I added the penalty, every time either of the players press it's button, they always get -2 points.

I think I might be related to the time.sleep bug.

For your convenience I put the code on Pastebin because it looks really bad and quite hard to read.

[Link to code @ Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KU02ZnDJ)

Comment: Could you please show us the exact error your are getting from Python?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to have the whole error for the time.sleep line

But aside from any errors, your LED is always on because you only have one sleep, the IF statements are "instantaneous". The code basically boils down to this:

```
while True:
    GPIO.output(led, 1)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2,5))
    GPIO.output(led, 0)
```

Which is basically the same as this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2,5))
    GPIO.output(led, 0)
    GPIO.output(led, 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: I realized I didn't answer question 2. I have a suspicion it's related to whether or not board is "listening" while it's sleeping, but I don't have any experience with this. Based on https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/ maybe you need to use GPIO.event_detected for example...